# ButterKnife cannot find symbol on Travis

Tags: android, travis-ci

I have a project which builds perfectly fine on my system, but when Travis attempts to build it ButterKnife throws out an error that a symbol for a library being used cannot be found.

I forked [Clans FloatingActionButton](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton) and then included it in the project by importing the gradle module through Android Studio.

When Travis tries to build the project, it throws the following error

```
/home/travis/build/tpb1908/AndroidProjectsClient/app/src/main/java/com/tpb/projects/project/ProjectActivity.java:81: Note: @BindView field with unresolved type (FloatingActionMenu) must elsewhere be generated as a View or interface. (com.tpb.projects.project.ProjectActivity.mMenu)
```

This happens for each BindView call I have for a class in the com.github.clans.fab package.

How do I go about resolving this problem?

Edit the views are declared in the layout as

```
<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
    android:id="@+id/project_fab_menu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:menu_colorNormal="@color/colorAccent"
    app:menu_colorPressed="@color/colorAccent">

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/project_add_column"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_column"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:fab_label="@string/text_fab_new_column"
        app:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorAccent"
        app:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorAccent"/>

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/project_add_issue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_issue"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:fab_label="@string/text_fab_new_issue"
        app:fab_progress_showBackground="false"

        app:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorAccent"
        app:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorAccent"/>

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/project_add_card"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_note"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:fab_label="@string/text_fab_new_card"
        app:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorAccent"
        app:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorAccent"/>

</com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
```

And then bound as

```
@BindView(R.id.project_fab_menu) FloatingActionMenu mMenu;
@BindView(R.id.project_add_card) FloatingActionButton mAddCard;
@BindView(R.id.project_add_column) FloatingActionButton mAddColumn;
@BindView(R.id.project_add_issue) FloatingActionButton mAddIssue;
```